# r: how to replace same specific part in many column names simultaneously

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have my dataset `t` comprising 1850 columns. Most of these contain `"fu1"` in their name. I want to replace all `fu1` to "v1"

A sample of `t` looks like:

```
> t
  symp_pre_rh_fu1___1 symp_pre_rh_fu1___2 symp_pre_rh_fu1___3 symp_pre_rh_fu1___4
1                   0                   0                   0                   0
2                   1                   0                   0                   0
3                   1                   1                   0                   1
4                   1                   1                   0                   0
5                   0                   0                   0                   0
```

But I want it to print:

```
> t
  symp_pre_rh_v1___1 symp_pre_rh_v1___2 symp_pre_rh_v1___3 symp_pre_rh_v1___4
1                   0                   0                   0                   0
2                   1                   0                   0                   0
3                   1                   1                   0                   1
4                   1                   1                   0                   0
5                   0                   0                   0                   0
```

I would prefer a solution in `dplyr` if possible.

```
t <- structure(list(symp_pre_rh_fu1___1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), symp_pre_rh_fu1___2 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), symp_pre_rh_fu1___3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    symp_pre_rh_fu1___4 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), symp_pre_rh_fu1___5 = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `names(t) <- sub("fu1", "v1", names(t))` or even `names(t) <- gsub("fu1", "v1", names(t))` but use `sub` in this case

Comment: Well that was easy. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Onyambu provided the easy way. A tidyverse approach might be to use `dplyr::rename_all`.

The second argument is `.funs` which will accept a function to apply to the names. In this case, we can use `stringr::str_replace` to replace the string.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
t %>% rename_all(~str_replace(.,"fu1","v1"))
  symp_pre_rh_v1___1 symp_pre_rh_v1___2 symp_pre_rh_v1___3 symp_pre_rh_v1___4 symp_pre_rh_v1___5
1                  0                  0                  0                  0                  0
2                  1                  0                  0                  0                  0
3                  1                  1                  0                  1                  1
4                  1                  1                  0                  0                  0
5                  0                  0                  0                  0                  0
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I requested - a `dplyr` solution.